# JQuery Sortable: How do I place a callback on adding an element, as well as whenever the list is rearranged?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to have a function callback whenever an element is either added, or when the list is arranged. I could use the update event for the latter, but I find nothing I can use to handle the former. Any input?

Comment: Have you tried `change` event http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change

Comment: Did you try using stop or receive ?

Comment: I did. I am currently using the stop, receive, change and update listeners. None of them catch them being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event. **This event is triggered when a connected sortable list has received an item from another list**.

Try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  receive: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Comment: This does not work for when an element is added unfortunately.